# Perceptron - statistical consistency

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification, perceptron

If training set is linearly separable then Perceptron finds linear classifier separating data with 0 risk/loss eventually. But what if we believe data are separable but they are not. In such case, if we would let Perceptron run on such data with number of examples going to infinity, will the error value go to 0 in such limit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error has an asymptotic value which is probably the minimum loss for a linear decision boundary -- that is, the perceptron finds (I speculate here -- you will want to confirm it) the best linear decision boundary, which, for classes which are not linearly separable, is some nonzero value. Followups to stats.stackexchange.com. Also, you will probably want to spell out exactly what you mean by perceptron since it is a specialized term which is not necessarily understood by everyone who might be able to answer the question, if they understand what you're referring to.

Comment: @RobertDodier Intuitively I feel the same. But one key difference is that I think that value of risk will be zero (in the limit) since if the number of examples is infinite then I think Perceptron will find such a decision boundary where the misclassified cases are the smallest number possible and irrelevant in size to the number of examples. Though I wonder if this is always gthe case. If not then it makes the question more complicated, since definition of statistical consistency requires risk to go to zero. But in a way the best possible risk also feels consistent.

Comment: As the number of examples increases, the number of misclassified cases increases too, right? By the way, further discussion on this topic should go to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is it possible to move the thread somehow or do I have to delete it here and start new there? Also if I may one more follow up, as the missclassifications pile up, you can always change the prediction rule. The number of errors would go up quite slower than the number of examples. If we get from 10 errors to 20, we change the rule and can get to e.g. 11. I'm thinking that there might be a way, but it is just my gut feeling, that with 'infinite' examples we can select such prediction rule that the number of errors is 'negligible' hence going to 0 in limit, but depends if it holds for all cases.

Comment: My advice is to just leave this question here and go to the other forum (whichever one you choose) and start a new question based on your current understanding of the problem. By the way, if the proportion of errors goes to zero as the number of examples increases without bound, that means we can construct near-perfect classification rules if we have enough data. Why doesn't that happen? Something to think about.